# Solved Angular Identifier 'title' is not defined. 'Movie[]' does not contain such a member

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

i'll trying to get data from backend via angular services.
i read angular docs and they said that we have to use interfaces when we want to send request to somewhere
something like this :

```
return this.http.get<Movie[]>(this.movieAPI)
```

so after that i tried to Subscribe to that service, everything works fine but i also
got this error from my compiler :

```
ERROR in app/movie/movie-detail/movie-detail.component.html:4:12 - error TS2339: Property 'title' does not exist on type 'Movie[]'.
```

its like my interface doesn't know the properties
this are my files

movie.ts ( interface )

```js
export interface Movie {
  id: number
  title: string
}
```

movie.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { Movie } from './movie'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MovieService {
  movieAPI = '../../assets/movie.json' // mock data
  api = '' // i removed my api 

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]> {
    return this.http.get<Movie[]>(this.movieAPI)
  }

  searchMovie(params?: string): Observable<Movie[]> {
    return this.http.get<Movie[]>(`${this.api}/${params}`)
  }
}
```

movie.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
import { MovieService } from '../../movie/movie.service'
import { Movie } from '../../movie/movie'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-detail',
  templateUrl: './movie-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-detail.component.scss']
})
export class MovieDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  params: string
  movie: Movie[]

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private movieSerivce: MovieService
  ) {
    this.getParams()
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDetail()
  }

  getDetail(): void {
    this.movieSerivce.searchMovie(this.params)
      .subscribe(
        (data:Movie[]) => this.movie = data
      )
  }

  getParams(): void {
    this.params = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
  }

}
```

movie.component.html

```html
<h1>
  {{ movie?.title }}
</h1>
{{ movie | json }}
```

[Updated]
in movie.service.ts

```js
...
searchMovie(params?: string): Observable<Movie> {
    return this.http.get<Movie>(`${this.api}/${params}`)
  }
...
```

in movie-detail.component.ts

```js
...
getMovie(): void {
    const id = +this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
    this.movieSerivce.searchMovie(`${id}`)
      .subscribe(
        (data:Movie) => this.movie = data
      )
}
...
```

Comment: At `getDetail`, I think `this.movie` now has an array of `Movie`s instead of a single `Movie` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface `Movie` has the `title` property but `Movie[]` does not.

In your code `this.movie` is of type `Movie[]` meaning it is an array.

The following will work:

```
 <h1>
   {{ movie?[0].title }}
 </h1>
```

If you'll change the naming from `movie: Movie[]` to `movies: Movie[]` it will be more intuitive.

You can loop the array with `ngFor`:

```
 <h1 *ngFor="let movie of movies">
   {{ movie.title }}
 </h1>
```

If `getDetail` should return only a single movie change the expected returned object like this:

```
 movie: Movie;  

 getDetail(): void {
    this.movieSerivce.searchMovie(this.params)
      .subscribe(
        (data:Movie) => this.movie = data
      )
  }
```

```
  searchMovie(params?: string): Observable<Movie[]> {
    return this.http.get<Movie>(`${this.api}/${params}`)
  }
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: it doesn't have any arrays , it's just a huge object

Comment: Your code expects for an array `(data:Movie[]) => this.movie = data`. what is the interface of the returned data from the api? You can init movie with an empty array to avoid this error. `movie: Movie[] = []`

Comment: i'm using shared interface , it's movie.ts

Comment: Movie is the interface for a single movie. `searchMovie` should return a sigle movie or an array of movies? What defined in the code is that it should return an array of movies.

Comment: i used this and it worked : (data: Movie[]) => this.movie = [data] as Movie[]

Comment: i think the problem was that , my received that was just object, and i had to put it into array of objects

Comment: `as Movie[] ` is not the solution. Doing so will only be a hack to fix TS errors. The right solution will be to change `movie` and all the methods related to it to handle a single entity - `Movie` instead of `Movie[]`

Comment: i really appreciate for your answers, based on your helps i find the problem , it was movie.service.ts , i used Movie[] interface and that was wrong , i changed that to Movie and it works perfectly. thanks again

Comment: searchMovie(params?: string): Observable<Movie> {
    return this.http.get<Movie>(`${this.api}/${params}`)
  }

Answer (score 0):

In your service the http request returns an array not a single object. Therefore the from the array you can't access inner properties. If the service has to return an array you can to the following

use ngfor

```
<h1 *ngFor="let oneMovie movie">
  {{ oneMovie .title }}
</h1>
```

Comment: thanks now i can read those properties with vscode ( now autocomplete worked ) , but i got another error

Comment: core.js:4081 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: the problem is that movie is null in the start therefore initialize the movie array with an empty array this way
movie: Movie[] = []

Comment: i got new error : core.js:4081 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed